# Push method is not working , it just show me empty array

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am adding error dynamically by pushing error message in array but when I call it in a function it doesn't perform any operation.

```
router.post('/Registration',function(req,res){
var path = '/auth/Registration';
req.assert('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
req.assert('email', 'valid email required').notEmpty().isEmail();
req.assert('password', 'password is required').notEmpty();
req.assert('cpassword', 'password is required').notEmpty();
req.assert('phoneNumber', 'phone Number is required').isNumeric();
req.assert('age', 'age is required').notEmpty().isInt();
req.assert('designation', 'designation is required').notEmpty().isInt();
req.assert('timing', 'timing is required').notEmpty().notEmpty().isInt();
req.assert('sex', 'sex is required').notEmpty();
req.assert('joiningDate', 'joiningDate is required').notEmpty();
var errors = req.validationErrors();
if(errors) {
    req.session.error = errors;
    return  res.redirect('/auth/Registration');
}
var errorsArr = [];
User.findOne({"username":req.body.username},function(err,user){
    if(user){
        errorsArr.push({"msg":"Username already been taken."});
    }
    User.findOne({"email":req.body.email},function(err1,user1){
        if(user1) {
            errorsArr.push({"msg":"Email already been taken."});
        }
        if(errorsArr.length > 0)
        {
            req.session.error = errorsArr;
            return  res.redirect('/auth/Registration');
        }

    });

});
var newUser = new User();
newUser.username = req.body.username;
newUser.password = req.body.password;
newUser.sex = req.body.sex;
newUser.email = req.body.email;
newUser.phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
newUser.age = req.body.age;
newUser.designation = req.body.designation;
newUser.timing = req.body.timing;
var CurrentDate = moment.tz(new Date(req.body.joiningDate),"Asia/Karachi").unix();
newUser.joiningDate = CurrentDate;
newUser.save(function(err,user){
    if(!err)
        return res.redirect('/auth/Login');
});
});
```

When I console `errorArray` it shows me an empty array.

Comment: code is executed asynchronously, so "if(errorsArr.length > 0)" is evaluated without waiting for the callbacks in checking the username and email.

Comment: yeah so than what should i do to check this condition?

Comment: can you show me an any example ?

Comment: Probably the 30th time today that there's been a similar question about improper use of async operations.

Comment: so can you show me any link or example for proper use of async operations ? it will be good for us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the findOne function is doing some database query. I am assuming.If so then it returns a Promise and you can not handle it that way.
Try this

```
User.findOne({"username":req.body.username}).then(function(user){
   if(user){
      errorsArr.push({"msg":"Username already been taken."});
   }
}, function(err){

})
```

Comment: so i have to install promise ?

Comment: no you do not. The user should be the value you are looking for take a look  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008433/i-am-using-node-js-promise-for-validating-either-username-exist-in-db-or-not

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using promise **$q** or simply nested or callback.

Simple nested code:

```
var errorsArr = [];
User.findOne({"username":req.body.username},function(err,user){
    // you should check err
    if(user){
        errorsArr.push({"msg":"Username already been taken."});
    }

    User.findOne({"email":req.body.email},function(err1,user1){
        // you should check err1
        if(user1) {
            errorsArr.push({"msg":"Email already been taken."});
        }

        console.log(errorsArr);

        if(errorsArr.length > 0)
        {
           req.session.error = errorsArr;
           return  res.redirect('/auth/Registration');
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: it show me an error "_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent"

Comment: it still show me an error i have updated my question full function for Registration.Please see that .Thanks