# i am using node.js promise for validating either username exist in db or not

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, synchronous

i want to check either username exist in mongo db or not i want to do it by promise , i am new in node.js please help me to understand actual scenario thanks in advance.

```
var errorsArr = [];
var promise = username();
promise.then(function(data){
    errorsArr.push({"msg":"Username already been taken."});
},console.error);

username(function(err,data){
    User.findOne({"username":req.body.username},function(err,user) {
        if(err)
            return console.error(err);

        return user;
    });
});

console.log(errorsArr);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: it show me an error username function is undefined and i am asking m i using promise in the right way or not ?

Comment: Not, it is not the right way. You need to create a promise first, before attempting to use it. The way promises are created depends on the promise implementation you use. Which promise npm package do you have installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose is already promisified, so this will do:

```
function findUser() {
  return User.findOne({ "username": req.body.username })
    .then(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // user exists, you can throw an error if you want
        throw new Error('User already exists!');
      }

      // user doesn't exist, all is good in your case
    }, function(err) {
      // handle mongoose errors here if needed


      // rethrow an error so the caller knows about it
      throw new Error('Some Mongoose error happened!');
      // or throw err; if you want the caller to know exactly what happened
    });
}

findUser().then(function() {
  // user doesn't exist, do your stuff

}).catch(function(err) {
  // here, you'll have Mongoose errors or 'User already exists!' error
  console.log(err.message);
});
```

A Promise is asynchronous so only return the Promise and the caller will "wait" for it to be resolved and handle the errors.

Comment: @user2377300 I forgot a `return` before `User.findOne()`. Should work now.